# Enter the code generated by your authenticator app?

Tags: authentication

I am unable to login to Heroku via their website.

I have the salesforce, google and authy authenticator apps, but none succeed.

I can issue the "heroku create" command, push my git repo, and see my application run, but I cannot login to heroku's website.

I understand that I may need to submit a ticket for support, but that requires me to login to the website.

I'm stuck in a Catch-22 situation, here.

Any help?

Comment: Do recovery codes also not work?

Comment: I have no option for a recovery code.  I have an option to login via SSO, but when I do that it doesn't recognize my email address.  When I login via command line, it shows me my email address, so that's correct.  When I login via the website, it accepts my email and password, but only gets me back to the "Enter the code generated by your authenticator app" prompt.